# What type of beer is best for beer battered fish?

Tags: fish, ingredient-selection, batter, beer

I was looking for a beer battered fish recipe the other day when I noticed most of the recipes don't state a style of beer to use.
Some of the recipes use a significant amount of beer so I assume that some of the flavor profile from the beer will carry over to the fish.

So I'm wondering, which style is ideal? Porter? IPA? Maybe a Hefeweizen?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The primary use of beer in a beer batter is its alcohol, which disrupts gluten formation and needs less heat than water to evaporate, improving the texture of the final crust. For flavor, most recipes using beer do best with a malty, low-bitterness beer, like a marzen, scotch ale, or (maybe) amber ale. Highly-hopped "put hair on your chest" IPAs are a bad idea: you don't want that bitterness. Hefeweizen would be fine.

A couple of commenters mentioned the carbonation as being an important factor. I suspect that it isn't. The volume of gas generated by evaporating the *water* in the beer will dwarf the amount of CO2 being released, even in the most highly carbonated of beers.

Comment: Alcohol and CO2 - similar to using carbonated water for thin batters.

Comment: Perhaps CO2 is the primary factor: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/beer-batter-is-better/

Comment: Prime material for someone running a cooking blog/vlog: Not necessarily "which beer is 'the best' for beer batter", but a look at the qualitative difference between batters with malty beer, hoppy beer, and whatever "flavour" people associate with lager. :P Also worth a test: heady beer vs flat beer with a view to defining carbonation's influence.

Comment: @Sammitch This definitely deserves a proper testing. For ehm, science.

Comment: Interesting. I've always loved Fish & Chips from a very early age. Once I started to get into beer, I found I hate IPAs, and greatly prefer as you describe "malty low-bitterness beer". Now you've got me wondering if there's a causal relation there.

Comment: Tempura Beer for lightly battered fish....

Comment: If alcohol is the primary purpose of using beer, the carbonation doesn't matter, and you don't want the flavor of the beer, then why not just use vodka or something like that? Another answer says some places use sparkling water. Someone needs to do some testing.

Comment: I'm partial to malt liquor over beer. It's more flavorsome. Dark Stout would likely be overkill.

Comment: Solubility of CO2 decreases rapidly with increasing temperature. Even in hot oil, water and even alcohol are going to vaporize much, much, much more slowly than CO2 will outgas. That may or may not be a factor.

Comment: @sneftel, just for the sake of curiosity, From where do you know that? I mean, what topics could I study for this?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Oh, just basic recollections from Physics class and such, and knowledge of carbonation levels from homebrewing. Beer carbonation tops out at not much more than 2 volumes of CO2 (two liters of CO2, at standard temperature/pressure, dissolved into one liter of beer), whereas the same liter of beer will evaporate into hundreds of liters of water vapor.

Comment: "It's because of the alcohol" is certainly compelling but it seems contradictory to experience where many batters are made with non-alcoholic sparking water. And since you're mentioning that there isn't much CO2 in beer as a reason why it's not because of the CO2, couldn't that also be said about alcohol? Beer has a very low alcohol content. If alcohol was the motivating factor it seems like there would be far better choices.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think the alcohol affects the tase in this kind of perparation. The point is to create surface of contact by using the gases in the beverage.

Usually in restaurants that serves this kind of dish they use sparkling water or any cheap beer. And for a extra crispness you can add the batter into a whipped cream dispenser charged with CO2 cartridges

Save the good beers to use in roasted beef, where the sugar in the beverage do affect the flavor of the dish.

Comment: I would disagree; the beer type you use can definitely impact the flavor of a battered chicken or fish.  For instance, I tend to use a stronger ale with more "beer" flavor to batter chicken, and the taste is a bit different that when I skimp and use a bottom-shelf American beer (think Milwaukee, Coors, etc).

EDIT:  It affects the flavor of the outer crust/batter, not the meat itself.

Answer (score 5):

There are several considerations. First off, anything you deep fry will take on a different flavor. I can attest specifically to hops in beer batter tasting wildly different and, in my and my dinner guest's opinions, disgusting. I would likewise be concerned with a heavier malt like a porter or stout.

Flavoring is really not the responsibility of the beer in the beer batter. The desired flavor (in my opinion) is that "deep fried breading" flavor that makes fried food so delicious. Other flavors just distract from that. In addition, you may also be concerned with imparting flavor to your oil. If you reuse oil repeatedly, then you want to fry things with as little flavor as possible, seasoning them afterwards, if at all. (Though note for beer battered fish! Once you deep fry fish you can't re-use the oil for anything that is not fish! However, I use beer battered vegetables as a side-dish frequently for big summer cookouts).

So, all in all, if you deep fry for larger groups several times a summer, you want a light American lager. Little flavor, plenty of carbonation, enough alcohol, and cheap to boot. I use Budweiser.

Answer (score 1):

The beer batter works because of the alcohol and the CO2 in beer. Bitter flavours aren't really welcome there.

For that effect, I recommend using carbonated water with vodka. You just get sparkling alcoholic water that way, without any of the flavours in beer that I don't think are suitable for battered fish.

If you do like a beer-like flavor with your fish, just go for whatever you like.